# Mid-sized black plate options

Tags: piece-information

I'm looking for a mid-sized (16x16, 20x20 ish) black plate for mounting on a wall. It can be a regular plate or baseplate since what I am mounting it on is not Lego and it doesn't need to fit into studs underneath.

So far I have only found this piece but no-one seems to sell it in black

http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=91405

Are there other pieces I should consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can piece together a 16x16 black plate in two layers, by making a base layer consisting of [3867 - Baseplate 16 x 16](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3867) (not available in black, but Dark Bluish Gray is a good option and given the minimal thickness it won't show)

[image]

and then putting 4 of [41539 - Plate 8 x 8](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=41539) in Black on top side-by-side.

[image]

Comment: I'd probably skip the 16x16 baseplate and just join the 8x8 with smaller pieces for my particular design. Strange that anyone selling more than 20 8x8 charges a lot more per piece though. I need 40 and anyone with that many wants $1.21 each, where as individual pieces sell for as little as 33¢ (NZD).

Comment: That's how the market works - if you need a lot, you pay more :) But think about the money you save versus having to get them from individual sellers and then paying for shipping for each smaller bundle. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I was really hoping for economies of scale :/

Comment: [LEGO Pick-A-Brick](http://shop.lego.com/en-NZ/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme) has 6x6 black plates for $0.87(NZD) per piece ... you would need 9 of them to create an 18x18 surface ... you're probably cheaper off getting them from BL in the 8x8 format.